# Запрос update не работает

Tags: php, mysql

Вроде правильно всё написал, выдаёт ошибку (Ошибка при добавлении данных!)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "UPDATE 'users' SET 'email' = '$email' WHERE 'login' = '$u_login'";

if(!mysql_query($sql))
 {echo '<center><p><b>Ошибка при добавлении данных!</b></p></center>';}
 else
{echo '<center><p><b>Данные добавлены!</b></p></center>';}
}

?>

//
 <form method="post" action="/?page=profile">
Введите E-mail: <input type="text" size="45" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Указать E-mail">

</form>
```

Comment: во-первых, прочитайте про PDO
во-вторых, напишите вместо 
mysql_query($sql)
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Не особо помогло

Comment: Какая именно ошибка мы тут телепатически должны догадываться?

Comment: http://take.ms/fVhxu у вас SQL Injection. [Читайте про PDO][1]

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/research/302421/php-pdo-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$db  =  new  PDO('mysql:dbname=db;host=localhost',"user","pass");

//далее сам запрос
$sql="UPDATE `users` SET `email`=:email WHERE `login`=:login";
$sth=$db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':email', $email);
$sth->bindValue(':login', $u_login);
$sth->execute();
}

?>

<form method="post" action="/?page=profile">
 Введите E-mail: <input type="text" size="45" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Указать E-mail">

</form>
```

Comment: и в качестве бонуса - надо обработку ошибок

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае переменная $u_login не определена и результат запроса = false

Comment: u_login определён, это не весь код